# Docker Ubuntu container on Debian host with custom CUDA/cuDNN

Tags: debian, ubuntu, docker, nvidia, cuda

I have access to Debian 11 server, where some arbitrary NVIDIA driver and CUDA versions are installed. However, since many people use the server, different versions of CUDA and cuDNN are required by many. So I decided to isolate my environment in docker, creating a container from an image [here](https://hub.docker.com/layers/cuda/nvidia/cuda/11.2.0-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04/images/sha256-101de8ef0921ec667c9bc2c2be4b990e26164266a7770d22ef74a018ade2e9cb?context=explore).

According to the guide on the internet, the host must have the NVIDIA driver installed (fulfilled) and `nvidia-container-toolkit` installed (fulfilled). Then, I created a container from the image by executing:

```
docker run -it --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.2.0-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04
```

When I connect to the image, I can successfully run `nvidia-smi`, but the version of CUDA is the same as on the host system, and cuDNN seems not to be there at all (the host does not have cuDNN at the moment, too), yet the image should contain both preinstalled if I understand correctly.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or how can I achieve to have an isolated container with a specific CUDA/cuDNN and, if necessary, driver version?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why the CUDA version shown by `nvidia-smi` called from inside the container showed CUDA version of the host, but I found out that I was looking for cuDNN in the wrong place:
https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/53
and it seems that the image works as it should. (I also installed nvidia-docker2)

For some reason the training times I'm getting are quite slow but I need to investigate this more and it does not seem to have anything to do with configuration of the image (at least GPU can be seen by Tensorflow correctly).